# Do you need to read Edgedancer before Oathbringer?

Tags: suggested-order, cosmere, stormlight-archive

I'm listening to the *Stormlight Archive* series by Brandon Sanderson and next in line is *Oathbringer* - due for release on the 16/11/2017 (in the UK).

I've noticed (via Audible) that there's another book in the series, *Edgedancer*, which they designate as 2.5 in the series:

- 1 *The Way of Kings*
- 2 *Words of Radiance*
- 2.5 *Edgedancer*
- 3 *Oathbringer*

It seems that, at the moment, there is no audiobook for *Edgedancer* and so, the question is, is it required reading **before** reading *Oathbringer*?

Comment: [Edgedancer is in Arcanum Unbounded](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Edgedancer), which you can get in audio (with the same very good readers as the main novels, Michael Kramer and Kate Reading).  https://www.reddit.com/r/Stormlight_Archive/comments/5f5gbr/no_spoilers_table_of_contents_for_the_audiobook/.  Edgedancer is the last story in the Arcanum, read by Kate, who does a great job with Lift's range of emotions and personality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Edgedancer* focuses specifically on two characters. Lift, who got an interlude chapter in *Words of Radiance*, tracks down the man she calls Darkness, who came pretty close to arresting and killing her (along with other mystery appearances in that book).

While nothing Earth-shattering happens or is revealed, those two characters go through quite a bit. So if they show up in *Oathbringer* (chances are pretty good) you may end up wondering what went on.

There are slightly juicy bits that relate to the world building:

> ... since Darkness has a connection to the mythology. Also, Hoid's conversation in the last epilogue is no longer that ridiculous (although still hilarious). Finally, yes, the two last seen in the company of Darkness, Szeth and Nightblood, are around, but aren't up to much yet.

If you're not interested in Lift or Darkness, *Edgedancer* can probably be safely skipped.

Comment: I would highly recommend the novella even to people who didn't care about the Lift chapter in WoR. I've seen lots of people on reddit mention that their opinion of Lift has been turned around by the novella. Also, there are a few interesting bits that don't relate directly to her.

Comment: I would also recommend you read it, if possible. Skippable or not, my opinion is that it's pretty good.

Answer (score 8):

It's not required reading, but I'd recommend it. It's very good and gives you some more clues as to the nature of things on Roshar.

Also, there is an audible book for Arcanum Unbound, which includes *Edgedancer* as one of its stories.

Comment: Just to give a bit more information about why one might want to read it: it's set between the end of WoR and the beginning of Oathbringer; the novella is about Lift (an interlude character from WoR), so it gives more insight into a Radiant order we haven't seen much of yet - also while many people don't like Lift from her interlude chapter, her character gets a lot more interesting through this novella; and the novella also contains some interesting lore, both about the man Lift calls Darkness and some other things.

Comment: @MartinEnder - Many people don't like Lift from her prelude chapter? She's only the best character in the series. :(

Comment: @Adamant you'd be surprised how many people dislike her (at least before reading Edgedancer). Just look through some Reddit posts about whether someone should or shouldn't read Edgedancer.

Comment: @MartinEnder - https://imgur.com/a/gOVo9

Answer (score 4):

*Edgedancer* deals specifically with two characters: Lift and Darkness

> Darkness is actually Nale, the Herald of Justice.

Sanderson has stated before that Lift is one of his favorite characters and that she will have a larger role later on in the Stormlight series.

*Edgedancer* flows in perfectly after *Words of Radiance*. I would definitely recommend reading it before *Oathbringer*.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good answer here. Just so you know, I have spoilered out part of this since it is not common knowledge yet.